# How to allign text properly in help screen for all resolutions in android

Tags: android, textview

I am having huge help text for my app.I am placing it in string.xml and trying to set to the textview in my help.xml file.I am able to display the text but not alligned properly. what should i do to allign text properly for all resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView11"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/help"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
```

I think by setting width to "fill_parent" and setting height to "wrap_content" you can achieve this. You can put that textview into ScrollView, which makes easier to move through your text.

I hope I understand your question well, or you can copy your code here.